# Strange eigenvalues result

Tags: symbols

I asked mathematica to determine the eigenvalues of a 3x3 matrix and the result it gives me is:

```
{Root[m^2 t - k1 m^2 vf + (-m^2 + t^2 - k1^2 vf^2 - k2^2 vf^2) #1 - 
2 t #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1], 
Root[m^2 t - k1 m^2 vf + (-m^2 + t^2 - k1^2 vf^2 - k2^2 vf^2) #1 - 
2 t #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2], 
Root[m^2 t - k1 m^2 vf + (-m^2 + t^2 - k1^2 vf^2 - k2^2 vf^2) #1 - 
2 t #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3]}
```

What do the '#' and  '&' symbols mean here?

Comment: Show your 3x3 matrix in your question. I assume it is symbolic?

Answer (score 3):

Please read the documentation. `Root` objects are space-age representations of roots, generally more useful than bronze-age radicals. `#` and `&` are shorthand for `Slot` and `Function`, building blocks of the "pure functions" that `Root` operates on.

```
ToRadicals[{Root[m^2 t - k1 m^2 vf + (-m^2 + t^2 - k1^2 vf^2 - k2^2 vf^2) #1 - 
2 t #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1], 
Root[m^2 t - k1 m^2 vf + (-m^2 + t^2 - k1^2 vf^2 - k2^2 vf^2) #1 - 2 t #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2], 
Root[m^2 t - k1 m^2 vf + (-m^2 + t^2 - k1^2 vf^2 - k2^2 vf^2) #1 - 2 t #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3]}]
```

yields a much longer expression in a representation that's probably more familiar to you.